# Update multiple values from an array with array_replace()

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sql-update

I am trying to do an update of a table in PostgreSQL.

In fact, I am trying to update an array. I have an table call switch_ids of OLD_ID, NEW_ID and I have the table TABLE_TO_UPDATE with a column my_array (an array of ids). I want to modify some of the ids in this array. I do something like that:

```
UPDATE TABLE_TO_UPDATE
SET my_array=array_replace(my_array,OLD_ID,NEW_ID)
FROM switch_ids
WHERE switch_ids.old_id = ANY(my_array);
```

The problem is that when there are multiple values to change in the same row (in my_array), it only changes one value and not all. How can I update them all at the same time? Nested calls?

Comment: You can nest the calls, yes. But your case is a sign that you really shouldn't be using an array to begin with: use a separate table to store those lists of ids.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can change the design. How can I do to nest the calls? What will it look like?

Comment: e.g. `array_replace(array_replace(my_array,OLD_ID,NEW_ID), OLD_ID2, NEW_ID2)` — as many as needed. Ugly, but works.

Answer (score 1):

There must be some kind of misunderstanding. [`array_replace()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) (pg **9.3+**) replaces *all* occurrances of the item, not just the first. Consider:

```
SELECT array_replace(ARRAY[5,1,2,5,4,5], 5, 3);
```

Result:

```
{3,1,2,3,4,3}
```

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/1952)

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)

> replace each array element equal to the given value with a new value